# periodical server query in Django

Tags: django, server

I want to create a web application in Django that checks some market data everyday at 9 AM and interprets them for users.

Now, how it should be done in the most elegant way? Should I create a separate app for it, that uses shared database with main app? Or maybe embed it somehow in the main app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very good question on this site since it's way too open to be answered properly.

However I'll try to give you some directions in order to allow you to research the topic more. There are two ways to implement your requirement (actually there are much more however I think that these two are the best ways to implement task scheduling in a django application):

1. Create a custom admin(management) command : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/ and call it each day through crontab (or a scheduled task if you use windows).
2. Use an asychronous task queue (something like celery or django-rq) and its task scheduler (either celery beat or rq-scheduler) to schedule your tasks.

For simple cases using custom admin commands is the best solution - using an asynchronous task queue is complex and adds some more moving components to your project (read my post @ http://spapas.github.io/2015/01/27/async-tasks-with-django-rq/ for an easy introduction to django-rq) -- however integrating with an asynchronous task queue gives you much more possibilities and freedom.